# Irssi: Using ALT + # to switch windows works for all windows but the first one

Tags: osx, keyboard-shortcuts, irssi, iterm

Somewhat of a bizarre issue, I'm using irssi in iterm3, and I have iterm set to read the left escape key as "+ESC" as this is how I've gotten irssi to recognize pressing option and a number key to switch windows. However recently, while this works as usual for switching to windows 2 or higher, I can't use this shortcut to switch to window 1. I have to type out /window 1 every time I want the main window.

Anybody have this issue, or know where to look? I can't see any conflicting shortcuts in iterm or anything.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough points yet to be able to add a coment, so I'll write my suggestions as an (incomplete) answer.

Make sure that the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> keypress actually reaches `irssi`, by running `cat` in a separate terminal emulator window or tab, and observing the output for this keypress.  If you see nothing in `cat`, then the terminal emulator eats up this keypress and you'll need to figure it out first.